# CakePHP & MeioUpload - WMV file not uploading

Tags: cakephp

I'm now using MeioUpload with CakePHP for my file upload component.

It works great but for some reason, when I try to upload a wmv file, it doesn't work.

Anyone has any insight?

Here is the setting that I have

```
'allowedMime' => array('video/x-flv','video/mp4','video/quicktime','video/x-ms-wmv'),
'allowedExt' => array('.mp4','.flv','.mov','.wmv')
```

So all other extensions work except for the wmv one.

Here is the var_dump result

```
        [file_url] => Array
            (
                [name] => 1wmvsample.wmv
                [type] => 
                [tmp_name] => 
                [error] => 1
                [size] => 0
            )

        [mp4_url] => Array
            (
                [name] => 1mp4sample.jpg
                [type] => video/mp4
                [tmp_name] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpG02Qdg
                [error] => 0
                [size] => 83427
            )
```

So the mp4 works but not the wmv.
The other weird thing is that with some wmv, $this->data will return empty.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this specific wmv file that you're trying to upload, as you can see, in the file array it returns in the index error the number 1.

This number 1, according with the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php), is a error that occurs when the file pass the limit upload size of the php config, so you need to change the upload_max_filesize in your php.ini.